# Modal displaying behind datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

**SEE EDIT:**

I have a modal which I'm trying to loop through and display each time in a loop.  I have the following code so far, I am attempting to get the modal to display on a button click.  So far it does not act as a modal and instead is displayed right under the button.  I feel like I am probably missing javascript but I can't seem to find the right thing online to use.  I think this is probably pretty easy and I'm just missing something. Any help would be great, I'm still new to this! Thank you!

```
  <label class="btn" for="modal-x">Add Map</label>

  <input class="modal-state" id="modal-x" type="checkbox" />
    <div class="modal">
      <label class="modal__bg" for="modal-x"></label>
      <div class="modal__inner">
        <label class="modal__close" for="modal-x"></label>
        <h1>Add Mapfile</h1>
        <%= form_for(@posts, multipart: true) do |f| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, :value => @location.id%>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.file_field :mapfile %>
          </div>
          <p></p>
          <div class="actions" id="submit-map">
            <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
          </div>
        <%end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT**:
I have figured out how to get the modal working, but now it displays behind the datatable I am using, rather than over it/in front of it.  Is there a property I can change that will bring the modal to the front?

Here is my css:

```
.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.modal__bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-state {
  display: none;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal-state:checked + .modal .modal__inner {
  top: 0;
}

.modal__inner {
  transition: top .25s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  height: 50%;
}

.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal__close:after,
.modal__close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 1.5em;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3px 0 0 -1px;
  top: 0;
}

.modal__close:hover:after,
.modal__close:hover:before {
  background: #aaa;
}

.modal__close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .modal__inner {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `class="modal fade"` to `class="modal hide fade"`

Comment: If you want access to lots of ready made modal functionality then you could use `bootstrap`: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: @MaxWilliams trying to avoid bootstrap for this if possible

Comment: @Pavan no luck on that

Answer (score 0):

Wrapp your div modal inside another div otherwise the other buttons in the loop will not appear.

Make sure load the bootstrap css and bootstrap js.

In your gem file have this.

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
```

And in your application.css

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

And your application.js should see like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Try this and restart the server.

Comment: I tried this and the button is still displayed but the modal is not on screen, which is good, but when i click the button nothing happens. Plus, again I would rather not use bootstrap, I have changed the button ID

Comment: You loaded the bootstrap js?